# is there some distrbuted stroage like Hadoop butwith the advantages of ZFS?

Tags: hadoop, solaris, distributed, nfs, zfs

Is there some distributed storage like Hadoop but with the advantages of ZFS?

Comment: Which specific advantages were you thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

You might find this recent blog entry by Ben Rockwood interesting http://cuddletech.com/blog/?p=562 . Ben is using Hadoop's HDFS to store and recover ZFS backups.  To me it suggests the strenghts and weakness of both file systems and combines the best of both.  Not exactly on target for your question but you may enjoy.